# Error 503 Service unavailable when using Apache with a Node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, express, server

So I'm trying to host a Node app on an Ubuntu server. Its a small "To Do" task app that allows the user to add, edit and remove tasks on a list that are loaded from and saved to a MongoDB collection.

Previously I've hosted this locally on localhost:3000 and it's worked well. The app works like so:

```
//1. The user goes to http://localhost:3000/ and receives the default HTML page via:

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/index.html")
});

//2. On load the HTML page calls a function from code.js that loads the tasks from MongoDB via:

//JS code
async function loadTodos() {
    let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/todos')
    let todos = await response.json()
      console.log(todos)
    showTodos(todos)
}
//On the app side
app.get('/todos', async (request, response) => {
    const todos = await Todo.find({})
    response.json(todos)
})

//3. After that all the edits, additions and removals are done the same way. The JS code uses fetch to a certain route and the app returns the values.
```

Now the problems come in when I need to use the Apache server.

I've enabled Apache proxy modules and set the proxy pass to:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
 ProxyPreserveHost on
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I've installed Express, Mongoose, Cors and iniated the NPM project.

I've added `Listen 8080` to `/etc/apache2/ports.confsudo` and `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

The file structure is like so, where code.js contains all the JavaScript for the HTML page and app.js for the Node-app.

```
/var/www/nodejs
--app.js
--package-lock.json
--package.json
--node_modules
--public
---code.js
---index.html
---style
----styles.css
```

The problem is that when I try to go to `http://[Server IP]:8080/`  I receive the `503 Service unavailable` error.

Could the issue be that I've used `app.get("/"` to access the HTML page and the Proxy pass `http://localhost:3000/` doesn't work with it?

I am quite lost.

Edit:

The 503 error seems to be caused by the res.sendFile process

Comment: Is your Express app actually running? 503 typically means that the proxy server (Apache) can't connect to the downstream service

Comment: Also, what does the Apache error log say?

Comment: The Apache error log entry is: "AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost". I switched the proxypass from "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 and added "ServerName localhost" but that did not help.

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. Any reason?